# Memory performance on vintage 486 computers using SpeedSys

Tags: memory, performance, ms-dos, intel-486

A seemingly large community of vintage Intel 486 computer enthusiasts use [SpeedSys](https://vetusware.com/download/Speed%20sys%204.70) (among others) to check whether their newly acquired/repaired machine works as expected.

This is what such a test report may look like.

[image]

I've got that picture off [here](https://www.amibay.com/threads/dos-benchmark-tool.45736/).

I'm particularly interested in the right lower portion of the mentioned image. It seems to depict a  (extended?) memory performance (throughput?) chart which is presumably rather typical for that kind of machines.

**My question is**: What exactly am I seeing there (the 'x'-axis has no label on it) and why does this 'stair case' pattern emerge? (I believe this has something to do with RAM vs. external/internal cache but I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is a memory bandwidth graph.

[image]

The bottom line is legend is most likely the read/write size in KB. The steps are the speeds measured to/from memory and are a signature of the various caches in the system.

What it effectively shows the following 3 things:

1. L1 cache (first/highest step) at 125 - 150MB/s
2. L2 cache (second step) at 20 - 60MB/s
3. Main memory at @25MB/s

The effect of using different sized transfers is that it can expose the cache sizes and see if your system is reporting a wrong sized cache.

1. L1 cache is most likely 16KB
2. L2 cache is most likely 256KB

Which seems to agree with the lines above.

Comment: So the tool SpeedSys does not know nor care about caches? It just writes to 'memory' and reads from it and measures the speed/throughput it achieves. By varying the size of data chunks it writes/reads at a time it finds that the throughput varies as well. The reason for that variation is that small data chunks end up being written to cache instead of RAM which is significantly faster. Bigger chunks don't fit in small caches and need to be written to RAM which reveals itself by its low throughput. Am I right?

Comment: @K.Nick It might be able to use a lookup from a stored database or query the processor to find out what the cache size *should* be, but that graph is showing what the caches actually are. Yes you are right in that smaller writes fit in the various layers of cache and by reading/writing to the same address in RAM but in incrementally larger block sizes you can effectively reveal the points at which the block of data no longer fits in each level of cache and ends up overflowing out of it.